# How to store background image from imageView in bitmap?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to store my image from imageView in bitmap, so that I can store it in the gallery of the android device. Every time I save an image, the background of the imageView is not stored. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();
```

Code to store the image into the gallery is:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            File dir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MyAlbum");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MyAlbum", "failed to create directory");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to make directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PICTURE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(dir));
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Have you any adapter? Can you share related locations code

Comment: where is the rest code to store the image into storage??

Comment: @ankitDemonstrate you can see the code to store the image into the storage now

Comment: if everything is fine, have you checked runtime permission for WRITE_STORAGE?

Comment: You want to combine both the src of the ImageView plus the background of the ImageView into a single image and save that?

Comment: @elmorabea yes i want to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a screenshot of this view (ImageView) in this case, it will simply take what's drawn on this view at this moment and turn it into a bitmap you can save.

Answer is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android) already.

The magical part is that

```
ImageView yourImageView = .. // Get reference it to your view.
yourImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourImageView.getDrawingCache());
yourImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Ta-da you can use your snapshot `btimap`.

Comment: when I take the screenshot of the imageView, both images have different widths and heights. So the image with smaller height stretches and ruins the picture. @elmorabea

Answer (score -1):

you can try this out,

```
private void saveImageToStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "Image-" + image_name+ ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Happy coding :-)

Comment: your answer is completely different from what asked in question